# Modify Woocommerce Rest API so it only sends the users content

Tags: rest, api, woocommerce

We are looking at woocommerce Rest API and tried to find any solution to have a restriction on created api for certain user so its only that user tied data that is synced through his api keys.

Ex. User A gets api keys for his user, only products,orders,stock and customer for User A gets synced through his api keys not anything else.

Feels like its just a simple rule that can be added as a function.